# Regex: How to get all strings between slashes from URL pathname?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to get all strings between slashes from URL pathname until first interrogation mark if any using regex?

For instance, I can have:

```
/abc/def/ghi?foo=bar → ['abc','def','ghi']
/abc/xyz             → ['abc','xyz']
abc/xyz              → ['abc','xyz']
abc/xyz/             → ['abc','xyz']
```

I tried this javascript code:

```
'/abc/def/ghi?foo=bar'.match(/\w+/)
```

But I'm only getting the `abc`.

Comment: `.match(/\w+/g)`

Comment: Use a capture group `(?:^|\/)(\w+)`

Comment: Try: `/(?<=^|\/)[^\/?]+(?=[\/?]|$)/gm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex with look around assertions:

```bash
/(?<=^|\/)[^\/?]+(?=[\/?]|$)/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/T3iROa/2)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `(?<=^|\/)`: Lookbehind to assert presence of line start or `/` at previous position
- `[^\/?]+`: Match 1+ of any char that is not `/` and `?`
- `(?=[\/?]|$)`: Lookahead to assert presence of line end or `/` or ?` at next position

Answer (score 1):

An alternative without a lookbehind, using an alternation and a capture group  checking the value of group 1 in the callback of [Array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

If there is a group value, then return it, else return the match.

```
\/(\w+)|^\w+(?=\/)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DMSn8f/1)

```js
const regex = /\/(\w+)|^\w+(?=\/)/g;
[
  "/abc/def/ghi?foo=bar",
  "/abc/xyz",
  "abc/xyz",
  "abc/xyz/",
  "abc",
].forEach(s => console.log(
  Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1] ? m[1] : m[0])));
```

Or excluding the `/` and the `?`

```js
const regex = /\/([^\/?]+)|^[^\/?]+(?=\/)/g;
[
  "/abc/def/ghi?foo=bar",
  "/abc/xyz",
  "abc/xyz",
  "abc/xyz/",
  "abc",
].forEach(s => console.log(
  Array.from(s.matchAll(regex), m => m[1] ? m[1] : m[0])));
```